# WPF: rubber multipath controls interface

Tags: wpf, silverlight, path, controls, rubber

I have a card component with (see below). And this component has a some  paths inside and Canvas.
But they have not rubber (when you place it into the Silverlight page).

How to do it rubber if possibly ?

The sample of queen of heart you can find here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8AVeqop_fkjOFpGZUFvbTE3ejQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I do not understand the word "Rubber" (maybe 'cause English is not my native language).

Comment: Tonio - Choose you language and see here http://translate.google.com/#en/sv/rubber

Comment: I meant resizable control with stretch layouts.

Comment: Ok i understand stretch :) but not "Rubber". I think it's a bad Google translation... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Viewbox` : Put all `Path` inside `Grid` with good `Height` `Width`, `Margin` values and put grid inside `Viewbox` :

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid Height="250.246002197266" Width="179.378997802734">
        <Path Data="F1M8 ... 398z" Fill="White" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.797" StrokeMiterLimit="4"/>
        <Path Margin="24.008,19.949,23.562,20.618" Fill="#FF131F67"  Data="F1M130...207.687z"/>
        <Path Margin="26.852,21.476,26.825,22.004" Data="F1M11.39....758z" Fill="#FFE2CF00" />
        <Path Margin="4.65,8.681,4.65,8.679" Data="F1M15...5.584z" Fill="#FFD40000" />
        <Path Margin="25.367,21.05,25.187,21.582" Data="F1M80....205.543z" Fill="Black" />
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

How to find Margin of path and Width/Height of canvas :

1. In blend, select the 5 canvas ;
2. Right click -> "Group Into" ->
   "Grid"